# App won't run on Xcode simulator but will run on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wondering if anyone has ever ran into this problem.

This goes back to my other question where people are saying that codes just don't start working suddenly without reason.

I spent hours debugging my app going through every single line of code. It won't run if I launch my app from Xcode, simulator or iPhone. Yet when I launch my app on the iPhone without going through Xcode, it works perfectly.

I tried restarting Xcode and the same thing happened. Any idea what might be causing this?

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "Deck.h"
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "PlayingCard.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()

@property  (nonatomic, strong) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController

-(CardMatchingGame *)game{
    if (!_game) _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count] usingDeck:[self createDeck]];

    return _game;

}

-(Deck *)createDeck{
    return [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSUInteger chosenButtonIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender];
    [self.game chooseCardatIndex:chosenButtonIndex];
    [self updateUI];
}


-(void)updateUI{
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons){
        NSUInteger cardButtonIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton];
        Card *card=[self.game cardAtIndex:cardButtonIndex];
        [cardButton setTitle:[self titleForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cardButton setBackgroundImage:[self backgroundImageForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isMatched;
        self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];

    }

}

-(NSString *)titleForCard:(Card *)card {
    return card.isChosen ? card.contents : @"";
}

-(UIImage*) backgroundImageForCard:(Card *)card{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:card.isChosen ? @"cardFront" : @"cardBack"];
}
@end
```

There's a breakpoint at

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
```

In the debugger, it says `-0 [CardGameViewController setCardButtons:]`

And all my properties in the console shows up as nil.

Comment: I deactivated breakpoint and it did the trick. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a breakpoint on this line:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
```

While I've never set a breakpoint in this place in my code, I suspect what is happening is that *both* the setter and the getter are getting breakpoints.

And right before "`viewDidLoad`" would get called in your "`CardGameViewController`", that's where the XIB/storyboard would be loaded and the IBOutletCollection of UIButtons would be loaded as well.  Hence the breakpoint hitting.

If you turn that breakpoint off, I think you will have much better luck with launching your app on both the device and in the simulator.